# Content in owlcrowsel not showing

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Content in owl carousal not showing. Below is jQuery as we HTML code generated after owl carousal implementation. even no text appears in it. only navigation and dot showing. nothing else accept blank page. is this a width issue or what. i want to make it working.

```
$('.myclassname').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            dots:true,
            autoPlay: 7000,
            nav:true,
            mouseDrag:true,
            autoplay:true,
            addClassActive:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:1
                }, 
                1000:{
                    items:1
                }
            }



        });
```

HTML here

```
<div class="field field--name-field-product-new-application-se field--type-entity-reference-revisions field--label-hidden field__items owl-loaded owl-drag">           
            <div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-2240px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 8960px;"><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1110px; margin-right: 10px;"><div class="field__item"><div class="product">    
            </div>
                <div class="app-block">
                    <div class="card-image">                
                        <img class="product-new-application" src="hero_cropped%20%281%29_0.jpg" alt="" title="">        
                    </div>
            <div class="new_application_desc">      
                        <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><h3>jasdfhsdjf sdhfsdfsdkjfd.</h3>
            <p>sdfsdfsdvcxvxcxcvsdf</p></div>      
            <a class="btn-greenh" href="https://drive.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Learn More <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="long-arrow-alt-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M313.941 216H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v56c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h301.941v46.059c0 21.382 25.851 32.09 40.971 16.971l86.059-86.059c9.373-9.373 9.373-24.569 0-33.941l-86.059-86.059c-15.119-15.119-40.971-4.411-40.971 16.971V216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> --> </a>  
            </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1110px; margin-right: 10px;"><div class="field__item"><div class="product"> 
            </div>
            <div class="app-block">
                    <div class="card-image">                
                        <img class="product-new-application" src="cartoon_hero%20%281%29_0.jpg" alt="" title="">            
                    </div>
            <div class="new_application_desc">      
                        <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><h3>hgfhfghf jgjghj ghjghj</h3>
            <p>fdgdfgfdg dfgdfgdfgfd gdfgdfg</p></div>      
            <a class="btn-greenh" href="https://drive.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">fdsfdfdf <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="long-arrow-alt-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M313.941 216H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v56c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h301.941v46.059c0 21.382 25.851 32.09 40.971 16.971l86.059-86.059c9.373-9.373 9.373-24.569 0-33.941l-86.059-86.059c-15.119-15.119-40.971-4.411-40.971 16.971V216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> --> </a>  
            </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 1110px; margin-right: 10px;"><div class="field__item"><div class="product"> 
            </div>
                <div class="app-block">
                    <div class="card-image">                
                        <img class="product-new-application" src="hero_cropped%20%281%29.jpg" alt="" title="">          
                    </div>
            <div class="new_application_desc">      
                        <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><h3>dsggjgghj</h3>
            <p>sdgdfhgfhfgh</p></div>      
            <a class="btn-greenh" href="https://drive.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">dfgdfgfdg <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="long-arrow-alt-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M313.941 216H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v56c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h301.941v46.059c0 21.382 25.851 32.09 40.971 16.971l86.059-86.059c9.373-9.373 9.373-24.569 0-33.941l-86.059-86.059c-15.119-15.119-40.971-4.411-40.971 16.971V216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> --> </a>  
            </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1110px; margin-right: 10px;"><div class="field__item"><div class="product">    
            </div>
                <div class="app-block">
                    <div class="card-image">                
                        <img class="product-new-application" src="cartoon_hero%20%281%29.jpg" alt="" title="">
                    </div>
            <div class="new_application_desc">      
                        <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><h3>Trtttyryrtyt</h3>
            <p>dgdsfgfgdfgdfg</p></div>      
            <a class="btn-greenh" href="https://drive.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">fdgdfsgdf<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="long-arrow-alt-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M313.941 216H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v56c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h301.941v46.059c0 21.382 25.851 32.09 40.971 16.971l86.059-86.059c9.373-9.373 9.373-24.569 0-33.941l-86.059-86.059c-15.119-15.119-40.971-4.411-40.971 16.971V216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> --> </a>  
            </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1110px; margin-right: 10px;"><div class="field__item"><div class="product">    
            </div>
                <div class="app-block">
                    <div class="card-image">                
                        <img class="product-new-application" src="/sites/default/files/2023-02/hero_cropped%20%281%29_0.jpg" alt="" title="">   
                    </div>
            <div class="new_application_desc">      
                        <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><h3>dfgfdgdfgdfg</h3>
            <p>gdfgdfg</p></div>      
            <a class="btn-greenh" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_RFf-lHjG81Q3l7Gzp5qgA5aEW8YyfYW/view?usp=share_link" target="_blank" rel="noopener">fasfdsf <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="long-arrow-alt-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M313.941 216H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v56c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h301.941v46.059c0 21.382 25.851 32.09 40.971 16.971l86.059-86.059c9.373-9.373 9.373-24.569 0-33.941l-86.059-86.059c-15.119-15.119-40.971-4.411-40.971 16.971V216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> --> </a>    
            </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1110px; margin-right: 10px;"><div class="field__item"><div class="product">    
            </div>
                <div class="app-block">
                    <div class="card-image">            
                        <img class="product-new-application" src="cartoon_hero%20%281%29_0.jpg" alt="" title="">        
                    </div>
            <div class="new_application_desc">      
                        <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><h3>rthrtyrty</h3>
            <p>dfsdfadf</p></div>
                  
            <a class="btn-greenh" href="https://drive.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">sdfasdf<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="long-arrow-alt-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M313.941 216H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v56c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h301.941v46.059c0 21.382 25.851 32.09 40.971 16.971l86.059-86.059c9.373-9.373 9.373-24.569 0-33.941l-86.059-86.059c-15.119-15.119-40.971-4.411-40.971 16.971V216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> --> </a>
                
            </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1110px; margin-right: 10px;"><div class="field__item"><div class="product">    
            </div>
                <div class="app-block">
                    <div class="card-image">                
                        <img class="product-new-application" src="cartoon_hero_cropped%20%281%29.jpg" alt="" title="">          
                    </div>
            <div class="new_application_desc">      
                        <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><h3>gsdgfdgdfsgdf</h3>
            <p>dgdgsdgdf</p></div>      
            <a class="btn-greenh" href="https://drive.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Learn More <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="long-arrow-alt-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M313.941 216H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v56c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h301.941v46.059c0 21.382 25.851 32.09 40.971 16.971l86.059-86.059c9.373-9.373 9.373-24.569 0-33.941l-86.059-86.059c-15.119-15.119-40.971-4.411-40.971 16.971V216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> --> </a> 
            </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1110px; margin-right: 10px;"><div class="field__item"><div class="product">    
            </div>
                <div class="app-block">
                    <div class="card-image">                
                        <img class="product-new-application" src="cartoon_hero%20%281%29.jpg" alt="" title="">          
                    </div>
            <div class="new_application_desc">      
                        <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><h3>rtyryhv fghfghfghfgh</h3>
            <p>gsdfgdfsgdfgdf</p></div>      
            <a class="btn-greenh" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TdD38CQQf0I6krUtFfv-wyGu7zt7-kcL/view?usp=share_link" target="_blank" rel="noopener">dgsdgfdg <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="long-arrow-alt-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M313.941 216H12c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v56c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h301.941v46.059c0 21.382 25.851 32.09 40.971 16.971l86.059-86.059c9.373-9.373 9.373-24.569 0-33.941l-86.059-86.059c-15.119-15.119-40.971-4.411-40.971 16.971V216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> --> </a>    
            </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div></div><div class="owl-nav"><button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev"><span aria-label="Previous">‹</span></button><button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next"><span aria-label="Next">›</span></button></div><div class="owl-dots"><button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button></div></div>
```

I check owl carousal document

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Be sure the external CSS is linked.  
The ".owl-stage" styling shouldn't do this:  width: 8960px woah! By merely test blocking it, all the images become visible on page (albeit vertical).